# Plotting side by side bar graph using two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have 2 dataframes with the columns brand and count.

Example:

```
brand | count
------+-------
Gucci | 1234
Chanel| 234444
```

DF1 has more brands than DF2. I want to create a bar graph where the x axis is all the brands and the y axis is the count. I am not sure how to achieve this so I get a side by side bar graphs for each dataframe grouped by the brands.

```
  ax = df_pred.plot()
  prev_pred.plot(ax=ax)
  plt.show()
```

I tried this code but I cant get it to group by brands. I used sns.barplot to create separate bar graphs but I want to overlay them. I want all the brands in DF1 and so a few of the counts will be 0 for DF2 but that is what I want to compare. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You will first want to create a single dataframe with both initial data in it. For use with the pandas plot function you will need a wide form dataframe, for use with seaborn you will need a long form dataframe.

Comment: Ok so if i merge the dataframes (use a left join) how do I make each count column a bar?

Comment: Using `joined_df.plot.bar()` ?

Comment: If I do that I dont get the names of the brand on the x axis. Can I pass the df rows for the labels?

Comment: Feel free to make your problem reproducible inside the question.

Answer (score 5):

IIUC:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(Brand=[*'GC'], Count=[4, 6]))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(Brand=[*'GCXYZ'], Count=[3, 6, 1, 3, 5]))

pd.concat({
    'One': df1.set_index('Brand').Count, 'Two': df2.set_index('Brand').Count
}, axis=1).plot.bar()
```

[image]